# How to get more points along the route in Here Maps?

Tags: javascript, gis, here-api

I'm getting a set of points along my route but in the paths where the car is on a highway, the segments are distant. I'd like to get a finer granulation of the routing. Is it possible?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json',
  type: 'GET', dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
  data: {
    waypoint0: '59.159486,17.645687',
    waypoint1: "59.397635,17.891626",
    mode: 'fastest;car;traffic:enabled',
    app_id: 'VXZP5fwHfh2WQIWnp0Zx',
    app_code: 'NgKq-kVEUMKxxNpBKP_hBg',
    departure: 'now'
  },
  success: function (data) {
    moves = data.response.route[0].leg[0].maneuver;
    timeAvailable = 45;
    trackPoints = moves.map(function (d) { return { 
      lat: d.position.latitude, 
      lng: d.position.longitude,
      time = d.travelTime }; });

    for (var i = 0; i < trackPoints.length; i++) {
      smackUpArea(map, trackPoints[i], timeAvailable);
      timeAvailable -= trackPoints[i].time;
    };
  }
})
```

Optimally, I'd like t get a point every x kilometer or every y minutes driven. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get more fine-grained routing information, you can request the `links` that the route is composed of.  To do so, add the `legattributes` query parameter with value `links` or `li`.  This will add a `link` array to the response for each `leg` object in each route.  Furthermore, you can decide what information you want to see for each `link`, using the `linkattributes` query parameter.  You could include things like length and shape of the `link`, as well as the remaining time or distance on the route at the moment a user reaches this link along the route.  There's many other possibilities, which you can find [here](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-route-representation-options.html) (look for **RouteLinkAttributeType**).

So in your code, this might look something like:

```
  data: {
    waypoint0: '59.159486,17.645687',
    waypoint1: "59.397635,17.891626",
    mode: 'fastest;car;traffic:enabled',
    app_id: 'VXZP5fwHfh2WQIWnp0Zx',
    app_code: 'NgKq-kVEUMKxxNpBKP_hBg',
    departure: 'now',
    legattributes: 'li',
    linkattributes: 'le,rt'
  },
```

And an actual link returned in the response would look something like:

```
{
  "linkId":"-733185668",
  "shape":["52.5158286,13.3774424","52.5158286,13.3774424"],
  "length":0,
  "remainTime":249,
  "speedLimit":13.8888893,
  "_type":"PrivateTransportLinkType"
}
```

Comment: Great info. The only weak point of Here Maps (in my opinion) is that the APIs and support are a bit hard to find. It's not as widely spread product so it's easy to google the pre-existing questions. So happy to get this one answered, though. +1, definitely.

Comment: Also, do you have any idea why it's called *legs*?

Comment: Glad to help, and we appreciate the feedback.  I don't know where the name comes from historically, but a route has multiple legs when there's more than 2 waypoints (so there's an intermediate stop).  So if you enter more than 2 waypoints, you'll see that 'leg' array having multiple elements.

Comment: That's weird. Previously, I assumed that there **might** be more than two waypoints and entered *waypoint2: "1.2,3.4"* but there was no difference on the map, so I simply assumed that only 0th and 1st waypoints (i.e. start and end) were possible. Was I simply mistaken?

Comment: If the map was only showing the first leg, then yeah, there wouldn't be a difference.  But after adding waypoint2, there ought to be a second element in the leg array with its own shape that you can display on the map.

Comment: I'm not getting the maneuvers nor legs the way you suggest. Probably, I'm doing something wrong. Could you post a sample of the *data* value to execute in the call to the API that produces all the legs for, say 3 waypoints?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one possible solution, but this would not be optimal.
I would add shape in the route attributes as a parameter of the request. And from the response, iterate through the every two pairs of lat/long to calculate the route of them. This would break down the segment into smaller pieces. It is still not optimal like what you asked in the question though. Using time-based or distance-based isoline with start as center then get the intersection seems painful to me. Hopefully someone has a better solution to this.